# searching in python

Tags: python

I am trying to search a file to find all words which use any or all of the letters of a persons first name and are the same length as their first name.  I have imported the file and it can be opened and read etc, but now i want to be able to seach the file for any words which would contain the specified letters, the words have to be same length as the persons first name.

Comment: Should all the letters occur in the same frequency as in the person's name?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) (for permutations) and [regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) (for searching)

Answer (score 1):

```
def find_anagrams_in_file(filename, searchword):
    import re
    searchword = searchword.lower()
    found_words = []
    for line in open(filename, 'rt'):
        words = re.split(r'\W', line)
        for word in words:
            if len(word) == len(searchword):
                tmp = word.lower()
                try:
                    for letter in searchword:
                        idx = tmp.index(letter)
                        tmp = tmp[:idx] + tmp[idx+1:]
                    found_words += [word]
                except ValueError:
                    pass
    return found_words
```

Run as so (Python 3):

```
>>> print(find_anagrams_in_file('apa.txt', 'Urne'))
['Rune', 'NurE', 'ERUN']
```

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this problem this way:

- filter out the words of the length different from the length of the first name,
- iterate over the rest of the words checking whether intersection of first name's letters and word's letters is non-empty ([set](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) might be useful here).

P.S. Is that your homework?

Comment: PS-RE: Sounds like it, doesn't it. ;)